# AngularJS: after ng-change 1st select is getting empty

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using following code to get data from local json file and populating two dropdowns from it but after ng-change event fires 1st dropdown is empty.

```
   $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/local.json'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available

      var _data=data;
      $scope.places=[];
      $scope.toPlaces=[];
      $scope.places=data;
      $scope.getToPlaces=function(){
      var selected=$('#fromSelect :selected').val();
      console.log($scope.places[1]);
      var key=$scope.places[1]
      $scope.toPlaces = _data[key].to;               
    }                 
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        alert("failure");
    });
```

I am using code from this link: https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD and passing json file from my local machine.

After ng-change 1st select is getting empty.

Comment: Please post a plunker.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/heUnMz?p=info i m using this link and in home.js i have my code for dropdown

Comment: This plunker is not useful , please provide a plunker of your app

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DW7IJZz0uace6wDMWvDp?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem is within your markup:

From [angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect):

> When an item in the  menu is selected, the array element or object property represented by the selected option will be bound to the model identified by the **ngModel** directive.

This is the reason why it overrides the places array when it is selected.

The `ngModel` directive inside a select tag should just refer to another variable on the scope:

```
<select ng-model="selectedPlace" ng-change="getToPlaces()" id="fromSelect">
    <option value="">--Please select From place</option>
    <option ng-repeat="p in places" value="{{p.id}}">
        {{p.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now instead of `var selected=$('#fromSelect :selected').val();` , You can just refer to that varaible:

```
var selected = $scope.selectedPlace;
```

Comment: for date select box it is throwing error that duplicate key in repeater. how to resolve that?

Comment: try this: `<option value="{{d.value}}" ng-repeat="d in days track by $index">`